# IE6 absolutely positioned child element in relatively positioned parent with padding

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, positioning, padding

I have searched high and low for this, but cannot find reference to this bug or how to resolve it.

In IE6 if you have an absolutely positioned child element in relatively positioned parent with padding on the parent. When you set left:0; and top:0; on the absolutely pos. child with a width of 100% the child does not expand to fill its parent's width it behaves as if it takes the width minus the parents padding. It does not matter if you define a width on the parent or not.

Example code:-

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  background:blue; 
  position:relative; 
  padding:0 40px; 
  height:200px; 
}

.inner {
  background:red; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:40px; 
  left:0px; 
  height:50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Still some active in the corporate world.

Comment: IE6 in 2012 - tell me you are joking :)

Comment: This is a specific application which has to work in IE6